# Rails - Session not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a session that is set but it does not appear to carry over to other pages. I'm on Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.8.7. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Can you put in some code of what are doing.....

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue in Rails 3.1 when CSRF verification fails. This can happen if you use a  tag manually rather than generate it via one of the built-in methods provided by Rails.

Search your log file for "csrf" (case insensitive search). If you see a log entry showing a csrf failure, it's likely Rails is resetting your session.

Answer (score 0):

You may be losing your session between requests which can happen if it's not established properly in the first place. If you examine your cookies you may see the session identifier changing, being re-assigned, because of a validation failure.

It's also possible that it's being assigned to a domain that the browser subsequently rejects. This happens if an application is configured to use a specific domain, and is then re-hosted under a different one, even `localhost`.

Comment: Strange thing is that it works on one computer and not on another. So that tells me the code is right and some configuration is wrong on my machine.

Comment: You should clear out the cookies on that affected computer, at least for the domain in question. One problem I've found is having a cookie for `www.example.com` and `example.com` where some browsers visiting `www.example.com` will toggle randomly between the two assigned cookies, as `www.example.com` will use cookies assigned by `example.com`, sessions getting switched up without any sense or reason. It is for reasons like this that you should always redirect visitors to a singular, canonical URL.

Answer (score 0):

You might have not used csrf meta tag in your layout. Try removing ' protect from forgery ' in application_controller.rb in controllers folder. Then try running the app again, if it works then you didn't add tags to your layout.